# Trouble with Fill's color function with complex expressions in tradingview

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to make it so `if cskies = false` then none of the plots or fills will appear. I've got the plotlines to appear with the complex expressions, but the fills aren't being responsive.

I don't get an error in the pine editor when I click "add to chart" but I do get a study error on the indicator once it's loaded in the chart. So I am unsure what to fix. Pine reference says that `fill` can handle complex expressions for its `color`. I'm confused as to what I am doing wrong.

The first `fill` is the complex expression I am trying to use, while the second `fill` is an example of what will load without error.

I've also tried instead of putting the `color.rgb` in the complex expression and just using something basic like `color.red`, but I get the same study error. This is on Version 5.

```
cskies = input(true, "Crimson Skies On/Off")
AlienWeaponry = input(close, "Source")
Protokult = input(75, "Heavy Resistance")
FleshgodApocalypse = input(75, "Heavy Support")
OmniumGatherum = input(8, "Red Power")
Soilwork = input(8, "Green Power")

BillyTalent = ta.highest(AlienWeaponry, Protokult)
Incubus = ta.lowest(AlienWeaponry, FleshgodApocalypse)
ChildrenOfBodom = ta.highest(AlienWeaponry, OmniumGatherum)
Rammstein = ta.lowest(AlienWeaponry, Soilwork)

Trivium = plot(ChildrenOfBodom, color=cskies ? #640000 : na)
GreenDay = plot(BillyTalent, color= cskies ? color.red : na)
LinkinPark = plot(Rammstein, color=cskies ? #006400 : na)
FooFighters= plot(Incubus, color=cskies ? color.lime : na)

fill(Trivium, GreenDay, color=cskies ? color.rgb(100,0,0,85) : na)
fill(LinkinPark, FooFighters, color=color.rgb(0,100,0,85))
```

Comment: No errors here and the first fill works as you described.

Comment: What's your ticker id and timeframe?

Comment: I ended up figuring it out, I guess my script was filled to the brink? (It was like 450 lines long) and once I removed another fill function for a different portion then the code above worked fine, it worked fine when I used it independently as well